# Meaning of "--_mixed 009J33F94539089U_--" in tail of public key

Tags: encryption, jwt, public-key-encryption, public-key

I have a public key as:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAryQICCl6NZ5gDKrnSztO
3Hy8PEUcuyvg/ikC+VcIo2SFFSf18a3IMYldIugqqqZCs4/4uVW3sbdLs/6PfgdX
7O9D22ZiFWHPYA2k2N744MNiCD1UE+tJyllUhSblK48bn+v1oZHCM0nYQ2NqUkvS
j+hwUU3RiWl7x3D2s9wSdNt7XUtW05a/FXehsPSiJfKvHJJnGOX0BgTvkLnkAOTd
OrUZ/wK69Dzu4IvrN4vs9Nes8vbwPa/ddZEzGR0cQMt0JBkhk9kU/qwqUseP1QRJ
5I1jR4g8aYPL/ke9K35PxZWuDp3U0UPAZ3PjFAh+5T+fc7gzCs9dPzSHloruU+gl
FQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-------_mixed 009J33F94539089U_--
```

I don't understand what "--*mixed 009J33F94539089U*--" in the end is, and what it's purpose is.

This key is supposed to be used for creation of encrypted JWT, which is to be sent as payload to hit an API. I used [this website](https://dinochiesa.github.io/jwt/) to create encrypted JWT, but API hit fails when I use this generated encrypted JWT. But I had to remove this "--*mixed 009J33F94539089U*--" from my key while entering in the aforementioned website for the creation of encrypted JWT to be successful.

I am wondering if generating encrypted JWT without using this "--*mixed 009J33F94539089U*--" and using it as payload is causing the API hit to fail. What do I do about this?

[NOTE : The key I mentioned above isn't my actual key.]

Comment: **It looks like the trailing boundary of a MIME multipart entity** that wasn't separated as required by RFC2046 from the last part within that entity, which was your pubkey. This was likely in an HTTP[S] POST or similar request; MIME is also used for email, but people rarely send JWTs by email. Check the software used to send and receive this data. It is not part of a valid PEM pubkey, which is why you needed to remove it. BTW it wouldn't really matter if the key were real; the whole point and purpose of public keys is that they can be made public.

Comment: So do I just remove it from my key, and ignore it?

Comment: Ok, do I need a private key too to create encrypted JWT. I created JWT only with public key (which isn't working).

Comment: If you're talking about encryption with a private key then you are probably talking about *signature generation* which is a different beast.